# Getting branched data/graph data

Tags: python, json, database, graph

Let's say I have the following data and I want to find everything under the umbrella "immunodeficiencies."

```
startNode - relationship - endNode
immunodeficiencies - includes - B cell disorders
B cell disorders - includes - Bruton Agammaglobulinemia
B cell disorders - includes - Hyper-IgM syndrome
immunodeficiencies - includes - T cell disorders
T cell disorders - includes - DiGeorge Syndrome
immunodeficiencies - includes - combined B and T cell disorders
combined B and T cell disorders - includes - Ataxia-Telangiectasia
```

How would I do this? The data is in JSON btw so it's like this `{"startNode": "immunodeficiencies", "relationship": "includes", "endNode": "B cell disorders"}`

For just one non-nested category, it was easy. I did the following:

```
for x in range(len(peds_diseaseR))
if peds_diseaseR[x]["startNode"] == "immunodeficiencies" && peds_diseaseR[x]["relationship"] == "includes":
    List.append(x)
```

For a nested disease, I'm really lost. I feel like maybe I need a recursive function, but I have no clue. I was gonna type out the code I wrote, but I feel like it would be more confusing than anything and it doesn't work.

EDIT: Just added this, but it's not working.

```
var endNodes = []

func findEndNodes(start):
    for x in range(len(peds_diseaseR)):
        if peds_diseaseR[x]["startNode"] == start && peds_diseaseR[x]["relationship"] == "includes":
            endNodes.append(peds_diseaseR[x]["endNode"])
        if endNodes != []:
            for disease in endNodes:
                findEndNodes(disease)
    print(endNodes)
    return endNodes
```

Comment: What are the different relationships? Does other relationships than `includes` exist?

Comment: Oh and func is not a python keyword. The keyword you are looking for here is `def`

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm actually using gdscript, which is basically python with some minor differences. `func` being one of them

Comment: And yes, other relationships other than includes exist! `hx` (meaning history), `pe` (meaning physical exam), and `tx` (meaning treatment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Just a little bit of re-arranging and you will find the solution:

```py
peds_diseaseR = [] 
def findEndNodes(start):
    
    # declared inside the function, because you need a fresh one for every recursion
    childnodes = [] 
    for relationship in peds_diseaseR:
        if relationship["startNode"] == start && relationship["relationship"] == "includes":
            disease = relationship["endNode"]
            child_nodes.append(disease) 
            # If you process it now, you do not need to check if you have values in your list. 
            # Thus, less code, but more importantly, less states your code can be in.
            # It is very easy to get lost trying to make a mental map when doing recursion. 
            # Keep it as simple as possible! 
            recursion_nodes = findEndNodes(disease)
            child_nodes.extend(recursion_nodes)
    print(child_nodes)
    return child_nodes
```

As you can see, I only replaced `func` with `def`, and I removed the `var` keyword. That does not exist in python. You simply assign a value. There is slight but subtle difference between append and extend. `extend` will `append` all values in a list.

Comment: WOW thank you so much for this!! Especially for the comments. Very helpful!